# syntax unicode error pygame

Tags: python-3.x, unicode, pygame

In a project I'm working on, I have to load a few dozen images. However if  i try to load any of them, like this:

```
twoc = pygame.image.load("C:\Users\Z & Z Azam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\Scripts\Cards\2_of_clubs.png")
```

I get this message:

```
    "C:\Users\Z & Z Azam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\python.exe" "C:/Users/Z & Z Azam/Desktop/New folder (2)/Python Stuff/PycharmProjects/ProjectGambler/Graphics-Cards.py"
  File "C:/Users/Z & Z Azam/Desktop/New folder (2)/Python Stuff/PycharmProjects/ProjectGambler/Graphics-Cards.py", line 16
    twoc = pygame.image.load("C:\Users\Z & Z Azam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\Scripts\Cards\2_of_clubs.png")  # Lines 15-66 bring all the cards into the program
                            ^
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape
```

I have no idea what I did wrong. Is there anyone who can help me?

UPDATE: So I've gone and replaced every \ in the file addresses with /. Again, it works perfectly until:

```
    "C:\Users\Z & Z Azam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\python.exe" "C:/Users/Z & Z Azam/Desktop/New folder (2)/Python Stuff/PycharmProjects/ProjectGambler/Graphics-Cards.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Z & Z Azam/Desktop/New folder (2)/Python Stuff/PycharmProjects/ProjectGambler/Graphics-Cards.py", line 28, in <module>
    fivc = pygame.image.load("C:/Users/Z & Z Azam/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python35/Scripts/Cards/5_of_clubs")
pygame.error: Couldn't open C:/Users/Z & Z Azam/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python35/Scripts/Cards/5_of_clubs

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Minimal example that exposes the error:

```
s = "\U"
```

In Python backslash is used as escape sequence and [`\Uxxxx` pattern is used to declare unicode characters while keeping source code ascii-only](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/unicode.html#python-s-unicode-support). By using `\Users` in your string, string after `\U` is invalid hex number, therefore exception is raised.

Quickest fix - [mark string as raw](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals):

```
s = r"C:\Users\Z & Z Azam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\Scripts\Cards\2_of_clubs.png
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically you need to add a escape slash the other slash in your string. So you will end up with two slashes, like so:

```
twoc = pygame.image.load("C:\\Users\\Z & Z Azam\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python35\\Scripts\\Cards\\2_of_clubs.png")
```

Or the other way you go about this, is to change your backslash to a forward slash:

```
  twoc = pygame.image.load("C:/Users/Z & Z Azam/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python35/Scripts/Cards/2_of_clubs.png")
```